# Slow javascript execution in Iframe only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, knockout.js, xml-parsing

> **The Problem:**

I've developed a **web application**. It is embedded in a site with the help of an iFrame.

If I run the application as a stand alone (IE9) on say: www.example.com/webapp it loads in about **ten seconds flat** (it's a rather large application). Chrome and FF are much faster.

If It's embedded in an iFrame however, IE completely loses it with **javascript execution times up to 40-60 seconds** until the app is done loading. Once the application is loaded however there are no issues and it runs flawlessly.

**Recap: Stand alone: OK, in iFrame: Not OK.**

In the web application a few xml's are loaded, specifically a very large one which is about 8mb. The xml's are parsed and content is created using KnockoutJS. However this is not very relevant as **I've narrowed it down to the XML parsing which is done with jQuery.**

Stand alone the parsing takes about 10 seconds in IE9. Embedded it's around 40-60. I've consoled out the status logs and timestamps and I can physically see the **javascript is running incredibly slow embedded**. **Every trace-out takes 4-6 times** as long which corresponds with the increased overall load time.

FireFox and Chrome are immune and show no slowdown or so little slowdown that it's unnoticeable.

I've tried iFrame and Object embedding. Same results.

> **The question**

Do you know why simple javascript execution (XML Parsing when the xml IS loaded and in memory), would take 4-6 times longer when embedded in an iframe than in stand alone?

> **Bonus info**

**I'm not talking about page load here**. Everything loads fine. Even the host page. This is not yet another page is hanging until iframe is ready problem. the problem is the execution inside the iframe being slow. I've tried embedding on same domain, foreign domain, internal, external. Same problem everywhere. **As soon as I iframe the damn thing, load performance goes to hell.** Once it's loaded, everything is fine and everything runs very well.

PS: I hope the bolding of what i find is keywords is OK. It's supposed to be a help, not be annoying. I personally have problems focusing on large amounts of text.

**

> Performance Monitor while it's loading:

IE9**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w39pQ.jpg

[image]

Comment: Just to help narrow down what's happening here, can you monitor your CPU usage when ie is loading? (I'm trying to figure out if ie is actually running slower in the iframe, or if it is doing more work for some reason)

Comment: Sure thing! http://imgur.com/iYdMuPe Here it is, will link in OP as well.

Comment: That is a noodle-scratcher. Certainly looks like the computer is having to do more work when through the iframe. In earlier versions of internet explorer (ie7 etc) there was a phishing-filter that some people complained was sucking up CPU when iframes were present. The ie9 incarnation is called the smart-screen filter. Check to see if that is enabled, if so, try to disable it. Disabling instructions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930168

Comment: Turning off SmartScreen did not help, still getting ~40seconds of load time. It's really weird... if it was constantly calling AJAX i could maybe understand why, but the XML is cached and the only thing going on is parsing and DOM injection for later rendering...

Comment: Two wild ideas: 1) interference from the host page - have you tried embedding the iframe in an otherwise blank document without any scripts or other content of its own? 2) it's not script execution, but script DOM access from the iframe that's slow. Can you try only the loading / parsing part without outputting anything or touching the DOM at all?

Comment: Nevermind 2), I noticed you said you had it narrowed to XML parsing. What version of jQuery are you using? From the looks of it, current versions only use `DOMParser`, while older versions tried to fall back to `ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" )`. So make sure IE is not running the iframe in any kind of compatibility mode, or try replacing `jQuery.parseXML` with `new DOMParser().parseFromString( data , "text/xml" )`.

Comment: The activeobject is indeed used, but intentionally. If it's not used, load time goes from 40-60 seconds to something between 3-5 minutes in an iframe and 10seconds to around 25s out of the iframe. No pre-written parse function is used. We're rolling through the xml by looking up nodes and combining them to an object that is injected into the DOM :) Sorry it took a while for me to respond, had to run some tests and had intermittent work.

Comment: Interesting. How do you force jQuery to fallback to ActiveX? Is XML _parsing_ the slow part, or the processing afterwards? Which Document Mode is IE running in? Btw, if you include my name in a comment (@janfoeh), I'll get notified and can't miss your response.

Comment: @janfoeh I tell it to be actively used in case of IE. AJAX loads in 'text' instead of XML and the process is offloaded to ActiveX: var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async="false";
      xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
      xml = xmlDoc;
IE is running in edge/9, but 9/9 gives same result. :)

Comment: Ah, I was asking since you said you let jQ handle the XML parsing. And what's the slow part?

Comment: @janfoeh XML is loaded into a variable and it's traversed using .each, .children and .find. However this works fine stand alone, but takes 60 seconds in an iframe in IE :)

Comment: I get that :) I'm just trying to pinpoint exactly _which_ operations are slower. So it might not be the XML parsing, but the traversal operations that are affected? Have you tried instrumenting that part with [console.time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772183(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to narrow it down further?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62654/discussion-between-eirinn-and-janfoeh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently IE had a serious problem with getting attributes of an xml node through jQuery in a deeply nested loop. Changing this to pure JS reduced load time to about 15 seconds. Still not great, but much, much better!

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting element size with jQuery .height(n) and .width(n) can be extremly slow, you may use .css("width",x) and .css("height",x) instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, hit F-12 and confirm the document mode is the same in both instances.  If not, change the document mode of the outer frame to match..

If they are already the same, try instead to load the iFrame script dynamically after the outer page is complete.  Older versions of IE handle resource allocation oddly and could be part of the problem.

Granted, not the answer to your question but bringing 8 MB of XML to the client is quite inefficient.  Can any of this be stripped out or entirely processed server side?

Lastly, IE is slow to move and add DOM elements (compared to Chrome).  Your best bet is to add them all at once.  So if you are updating the UI as you parse the XML (instead of all at once after parsing), that will slow you down considerably.

Comment: Thank you for pitching in. Document modes are the same, iFrame is loaded on blank page without content. We can't use server side processing since the application is also meant to be loaded off-grid. The problem is only in an iFrame so i suspect the UI load sequence makes no difference in that matter:)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @ern0 said, if you are manipulating height and width in your script and are experiencing slowness then changing from using jQuery's `.height()` and `.width()` methods to vanilla JS could realize a significant performance improvement.

**Getters**

Here is a [performance test](http://jsperf.com/height-vs-offsetheight-vs-cssheight/2) for reading the element's current height. It shows that the vanilla JS property `offsetHeight` is *significantly faster* than the `.height()`, `.css("height")` and `.style.height` techniques.

The difference is so significant that it is not even a competition.

**Setters**

Here is a [performance test](http://jsperf.com/setting-height-with-height-vs-css-vs-style-height) for setting the element's current height. It shows that the vanilla JS property `.style.height` is *significantly* faster* than the `.height()`, and `.css("height")` methods.

Again, the difference is so significant that it is not even a competition.

**Summary**

The `.style.height` property excels in both getting and setting by an incredible margin, as compared to the jQuery methods. The read-only `offsetHeight` property is significantly faster than the `style.height` property for getting, but (as it is read-only) it cannot be used for setting the height. As such, it may be easier to just change the code to use `.style.height`, if it still achieves the desired effect.

The height and width properties and methods should be pretty much the same. If you want to add performance benchmarks for them too, that is fine, but you should get the same outcome, with the width properties and methods finishing in the same place as their corresponding height counterparts.